How to Extend ASP.NET Session Timeout in Plesk?
I'm currently hosting my ASP.NET Core application using Plesk, but I'm encountering an issue where the session times out after 20 minutes of inactivity, redirecting users to the login page. I would like to extend the session timeout so that users can remain logged in for a longer period.
I have already added the following code to my Program.cs file, but it hasn't resolved the issue:

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Account/logout";
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
        options.Cookie.MaxAge = options.ExpireTimeSpan;
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true; 
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;

        options.Events.OnSigningIn = (context) =>
        {
            context.CookieOptions.Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(365);
            context.CookieOptions.MaxAge = options.ExpireTimeSpan;
            context.Properties.AllowRefresh = true;
            context.Properties.IsPersistent = true;
            
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });


builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Events.OnSigningIn = ctx =>
    {
        var issued = ctx.Properties.IssuedUtc ?? DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        ctx.Properties.ExpiresUtc = issued.AddDays(365);
        ctx.Properties.AllowRefresh = true;

        ctx.CookieOptions.Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(365);
        ctx.CookieOptions.MaxAge = options.ExpireTimeSpan;

        ctx.Properties.IsPersistent = true;

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    };
    options.Events.OnSigningIn = (context) =>
    {
        context.CookieOptions.Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(365);
        context.CookieOptions.MaxAge = options.ExpireTimeSpan;
        context.Properties.AllowRefresh=true;
        context.Properties.IsPersistent=true;
        
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});


What additional steps should I take to ensure the session timeout is extended? Are there specific configurations in Plesk or IIS that I need to adjust?
Thank you for your assistance!

Your problem should be in asp.net core, you can try to modify IdleTimeout.
The IdleTimeout indicates how long the session can be idle before its contents are abandoned. Each session access resets the timeout. This setting only applies to the content of the session, not the cookie. The default is 20 minutes.
More information you can refer to this link: Session options.

Thanks a lot, I do it but not working for me...!

I modified my answer, hope this method can solve your problem.
